# Practical examples of Client-centric consistency

Tags: system, distributed, eventual-consistency

In the Distributed systems : principles and paradigms : by  Maarten van Steen and Tanenbaum. 3rd edition

Chapter 7 : Consistency and Replication.

I am trying to understand the difference between Client-centric consistency and Data-centric consistency.

Practical examples of client-centric consistency.
- Monotonic Reads.
- Monotonic Writes.
- Read your writes.
- Writes follow your reads.

There are already examples in the book about web-based mail application for explaining the eventual consistency.

But I'm still not convinced as to where are these exactly used.

If anyone could point me to any material or explain with some practical scenarios where these consistency models are used. It'll be very helpful.

Thanks!